# Homotopy Fibers of homotopy equivalence.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've been trying to show the following:

EDIT: Let $X$ and $Y$ be compactly generated topological spaces.

$f: X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence if and only if the homotopy fibers of $f$ are contractible.

I've seen this result mentioned frequently, but I'm struggling to come up with a proof for it.

Sorry for not uploading attempts, but they've all been fruitless.

Comment: I'm not sure how general the statement is, but if the homotopy fiber is a CW complex, it follows from Whitehead's theorem.  I don't know if the homotopy fiber is always a CW complex (if X and Y are).

Comment: The homotopy fibre of a map between CW complexes is again CW, since it is homotopy equivalent to the pullback of the path space fibration, which is CW.

Comment: I see why Whitehead's Theorem is needed to show that a contractible homotopy fiber yields a homotopy equivalence. I still can't see why a homotopy equivalence should give a contractible fiber.

Comment: A homotopy equivalence should give a weakly contractible fibre. Whitehead's theorem then guarantees you contractibility of the fibre if it is CW. Note that it may still be contractible even if it is not CW, and it may be CW even if X,Y are not.

Answer (score 0):

My spaces are CW complexes and path connected. The point of the homotopy fiber is to turn any map into a fibration, i.e. replace a nasty map $X\rightarrow Y$, into a fibration sequence

$$
F\rightarrow \tilde X\rightarrow Y
$$

Now consider the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of a fibration

$$
\ldots \rightarrow \pi_n(F)\rightarrow \pi_n(\tilde X)\rightarrow \pi_n( Y)\rightarrow \pi_{n-1}(F)\rightarrow \ldots
$$

All the maps $\pi_n(\tilde X)\rightarrow \pi_n(Y)$ are isomorphisms if and only if $\tilde f$ is a homotopy equivalence (Whitehead's theorem). This occurs precisely if and only if $\pi_n(F)=0$ for all $n$. But this implies that $F$ is contractible.

Comment: So it seems to me, that the only requirement of CW complex is to use whiteheads theorem. We get “for free” that the homotopy groups are isomorphic when the underlying map is a homotopy equivalence. So... one direction works without whiteheads, and the other doesn’t